# Working in United Kingdom after 1 year of post Graduate Study Possible for Asian country students

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, student-visa, uk-visa

I am an Indian, and I am planning to apply for a British university [course](https://www.condenastcollege.ac.uk/courses/postgraduate/ma-fashion-media-practice/).
Will I get the opportunity to get work after that because I will rely mostly on loans from the home country. In order to pay heavy loans, I need to work in the UK for 1-2 years minimum.

In the USA such courses allow 1Y OPT extension, and in case of stem degree, even 3 years work permit under OPT.

How about the same in the United Kingdom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the UK abolished the post study work visa in 2012, as part of Theresa May's policy as Home Secretary to reduce the number of international students in the UK. Furthermore, she subsequently changed Home Office policy to reduce the period after the projected end of course which visas would be set to expire.

However, her successor Home Secretaries have somewhat less zeal for destroying the UK's university sector, and there have been policy changes to [extend the length of time for which the visa is valid after studying](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2019/mar/16/visa-extension-overseas-students-uk-brexit). It also seems possible that [the post study work visa may be reintroduced at some point in the future](https://www.ft.com/content/74d7920a-8835-11e9-a028-86cea8523dc2).

Also, it is possible to switch in-country from a Tier 4 (study) visa to a Tier 2 (work) visa assuming you find a licensed employer.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on the type of visa issed by the UK Government.

https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas

International students who study a full-time undergraduate or postgraduate degree course at a recognised university *are allowed to work part-time during term term for up to 20 hours a week* and full-time during the holidays.

Non-EU students who wish to remain in the UK *after they have graduated must apply for a work visa* from UK Visa and Immigration.  There are several visas you can apply for as a London graduate:

https://www.studylondon.ac.uk/application-advice/working-in-london-and-the-uk

Answer (score 1):

For now, you get a 4 months period after the end of your full time study at any university in UK. If you are lucky enough or super genius, you can end up finding an employer who gets you onboard with a tier 2 work visa. But it is not easy at all, and majority of students who come with the hope of finding a job and settling down in UK after spending so much money in their education, end up leaving without any positive results.
Make sure you understand the pros and cons of studying in UK on a tier 4 visa before taking a decision.